# PHP mail function not working based on the body of the message

Tags: php, email

so on my server I tried running:

```
mail('my@email.com', 'asdf', 'asklfdjksalfdsdaf I know I I know I');
```

and PHP sent the mail perfectly....but then when I changed the message to

```
mail('my@email.com', 'asdf', 'hahahahaa');
```

it did NOT send the email to me....

what can possibly cause this? the only thing that's different is the message body...I am completely baffled...

Comment: before anything else? is the smtp configured??

Comment: Did you check your spamfolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way I send messages with php and avoid sending to spam folder:

```
<?php

$to = "test@test.com";
$subject = "Test Email";
$message = "Test Email";

// normal headers
$num = md5(time()); 
$headers  = "From: Mailer <mailer@test.com>\r\n";
$headers  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers  .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers  .= "boundary=".$num."\r\n";
$headers  .= "--$num\r\n";

// This two steps to help avoid spam   

$headers .= "Message-ID: <".time()." TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion()."\r\n";         

// With message

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
$headers .= "".$message."\n";
$headers .= "--".$num."\n"; 


@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your spam filter. It is possible that it is catching the message as being too short or not having enough discernible words, or any one of the other hundred things they'll check for.

If it is the spam filter, another thing that will help is adding different headers to help validate the email. Sometimes simply adding a realistic FROM in the headers can allow it through a spam filter.  There's a default FROM set, usually in your php.ini but if it's some system generated name then filters can flag it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```